# Unclear description on Etherscan

Tags: transactions, transaction-trace

On Etherscan, when I hover over the "?" on the "From" field I see the following:

`The sending party of the transaction (could be from a contract address).`

I don't understand. I thought only an EOA could initiate a transaction? Internal traces of course can come from contracts, but not the initial (I thought).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, a transaction can only start from an EOA, and never from a contract. You should poke Etherscan to fix their texts.